# pre order on the category page

Tags: magento2, php, addtocart, quantity, backorder

How to change the label of add to cart to pre order on all magento `2.4.5` based on the below conditions:

```
if(qty<0 , product is salable and getBackorders()/true )
```

to show pre order else add to cart.

Please suggest a way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

1. First create `catalog_category_view.xml` into your custom extension at following path.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\layout\catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Extension::catalog/product/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

2. Now copy the magento default category list file from :

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

to

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\templates\catalog\product\list.phtml

3. now into your extension file, you need to put conditions before `Add To Cart` Button according to your requirements.